# how do i test for the value TRUE in excel

Tags: excel

Quick one (hopefully)

I have a column in excel 2010 that has either the value TRUE or FALSE in the cell

I want to copy the value of another cell if the value is TRUE

Here's what I have:

```
A1 some value
B1 TRUE
C1 =IF(B1=TRUE,A1,"")
```

I have tried the following (none of which work):

```
=IF(B1=TRUE,...
=IF(B1="TRUE",...
=IF(B1,...
```

I have also tried column B as General and as Text

I have noticed that if I type the word TRUE or FALSE into the B column it left aligns it instead of being centred which may give some clues.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: I must say, your first attempt works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you type TRUE or FALSE into a cell they default to "Boolean values" (not text) so you don't use quotes, in which case your first formula should work, i.e.

`=IF(B1=TRUE,A1,"")`

....however, if the column is formatted as text you would need quotes like

`=IF(B1="TRUE",A1,"")`

If neither work then perhaps there are some leading or trailing spaces in B1?

Comment: They were initially calculated boolean values and were pasted (Values only) to a new sheet which marked them as general, none of my three attempts worked, so I changed the column to text, still not working, then I did a search and replace and change FALSE to 'FALSE and TRUE to 'TRUE - still didn't work

Comment: You can test whether the value is text =ISTEXT(B1).....or a "logical value" (Boolean) =ISLOGICAL(B1), depending which it is I would expect one of those two formulas to work......

Comment: I have done it again, and it works as it should this time.  Must have got itself in a muddle the first time round - thanks for your efforts anyway - the odd thing is that I duplicated the problem on somebody elses machine - just one of those excel quirks I guess.